# how to insert a datepicker datetime value into sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, datepicker

My SQL Server 2008 database has a table with a column of datatype `datetime`.

When I try to insert values into the `datetime` column I am getting error.

> *Incorrect syntax near '-'*

My datetime picker has custom format `yyyy-MM-dd` e.g (2012-11-01)

Following is the code sample I used to insert `datetime`.

```
 System.DateTime myDate = default(System.DateTime);
 myDate = DateTimePickerPrint.Value;
 string query = string.Format("EXEC Save_Quotation_Bookshop '" + txt_QutationNo.Text + "','" + txt_CusCode.Text + "',#" + myDate + "#,");
```

Please any one have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: **STOP** concatenating together your SQL code! This is an invitation for SQL injection attacks, and it's really bad for performance, too - use **parametrized queries** instead.

If you do - you won't have the problem of datetime/string conversion issues, either.....

Secondly: the "safe" format for a date-only `DateTime` in SQL Server is `YYYYMMDD` - **without any dashes** - only this format guarantees that it'll run on any SQL Server, regardless of your language, regional and dateformat settings.

Thirdly. if you want to execute a stored procedure - I would recommend using this approach:

```
System.DateTime myDate = default(System.DateTime);
myDate = DateTimePickerPrint.Value;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(your-connection-string-here))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Save_Quotation_Bookshop", con))
{
    // tell ADO.NET it's a stored procedure (not inline SQL statements)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // define parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuotationNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_QutationNo.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCode", SqlDbtype.VarChar, 25).Value = txt_CusCode.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SaleDate", SqlDbType.DataTime).Value = myDate;

    // open connection, execute stored procedure, close connection again
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Don't use `EXEC ......` as an inline SQL statement - tell ADO.NET that you're executing a stored procedure, supply the parameters - and you're done!

Comment: thnx for replying, Its working by removing EXEC ADO.NET,and execute thorough ADO.NET

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the date in single quotes instead of #.

This string concatenation is a SQL injection waiting to happen.  Use SqlCommand with parameters instead, then you don't have to worry about string conversion issues

Comment: Thnx for replying, I used SqlCommand with parameters but it gives following error. But can you put a code sample for Wrap the date in single quotes instead of #

Comment: Implicit conversion from data type datetime to decimal is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string query = String.Format("EXEC Save_Quotation_Bookshop '{0}','{1}','{2}'",txt_QutationNo.Text,txt_CusCode.Text, myDate);
```

OR

```
string query = string.Format("EXEC Save_Quotation_Bookshop @QutationNo,@CusCode,@myDate");

...
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QutationNo", txt_QutationNo.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CusCode", txt_CusCode.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myDate", myDate);
```

Comment: I tried, but when I put single qutation It gives Error : Error converting data type varchar to decimal.

Comment: make sure you are placing each parameter in their respective order

Comment: Thnx for replying  @codingbiz. I will try this.